# Sequential equation numbering when using 'report' class

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, report

I would like to use sequential equation numbering but I am using the [`report`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/report) class which defaults to numbering equations within chapters. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can use `chngcntr` package with its `\counterwithout`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{equation}
  x=y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  x=z
\end{equation}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{equation}
  x \neq y
\end{equation}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\begin{equation}
  x= a + y
\end{equation}    
%
\end{document}
```